# Adverb for the number of people

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Is there an adverb in English that can be used to refer to the number of people who do an action?
For example we say

> Henry, Frank and Alex pulled the heavy box together.

Is there a structure like an adverb to put here as in

> They pulled the heavy box [...]

An adveb which probably means *in a group of three* or something like that.
We have this type of adverb in our native language so I was wondering if it does exist in English, too. I have never seen it though.
It is supposed to be a kind of contrastive analysis!

Comment: In *they pulled the heavy box in a group of three*, *in a group of three* acts as an adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 1):

They  pulled the box **together.**
alternative: as a threesome. [adverbial phrase]

**Together** answers the question: How did they pull the box?

Therefore, it is an adverb.

Questions that ask how something is done usually is related to verbs. Therefore,the words are adverbs.

The many walk down the street fast.

How did they walk down the street? Fast.

Fast=adverb.

:)

Comment: I think you did not get my question. I know what an adverb is and I know 'together' is an adverb. I'd like to know if there is an adverb in English that specifically refers to the number of people. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, as asked, "The three of them pulled the box together" makes together an adverb. We have triply but it wouldn't work here. The actor was triply famous: an an actor, painter and singer. It doesn't work for action verbs like pull,where you have already specified there were three pulling the box. Anything else? Or have I still not understood you? Fyi, an adverb can never refer to a "number of people". "An adverb has to refer to a verb, that is why it is an ad-verb i.e. something you add to a verb," she added glibly.